# file paths in mercurial repository too long for windows

Tags: mercurial

I have committed some files to a mercurial repository that I want to permanently remove from the repository history. Its just test output in a directory that I hadn't added to .hgignore. I wouldn't normally care, but the file paths are very long and when I try to clone to a windows machine it aborts due the file path length.

I've read in a few places that its not possible to remove history. Is there any other workaround?

Comment: You can probably use `hg convert` with a filemap to move the offending files, or get rid of them, but I've never used it so I won't add that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* remove files from the history completely, but by doing so, you're basically creating a new repository, unrelated to the previous one (so any clone it has will no longer be a clone). The easiest way is to use convert extension:

```
hg convert -d hg --filemap filemap repo new-repo
```

The `filemap` file allows you to specify which files should be skipped over when creating the new history:

```
exclude fileA
exclude fileB
```

You can find more information on the Mercurial wiki: [convert extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_Mercurial), [FAQ entry](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2BAC8-CommonProblems.I_committed_a_large_binary_file.2BAC8-files_how_do_I_delete_them_permanently.3F).